# Создание выпадающего списка, пункты которого являются значениями переменных из javascript

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть файл HTML, в котором мне нужно создать выпадающий список. Но пункты этого списка должны быть заданы через js (это нужно для дальнейшей работы).
Код js

```
function Point(){
    this.parent = "no";
    this.name = "root";
    this.id = "0";
    this.kids = [];
    this.kidscount = 0;
};

function NewPoint(ItParent, name, id){
    this.parent = ItParent;
    this.name = name;
    this.id = ItParent.id + "." + id;
    this.kids = [];
    this.kidscount = 0;
    ItParent.kids[ItParent.kidscount] = this;
    ItParent.kidscount = ItParent.kidscount + 1;
};

var start_point = new Point();
    var genre1 = new NewPoint(start_point, "post-apocalypse", "1");
        var genre1_1 = new NewPoint(genre1, "zombie", "1");
        var genre1_2 = new NewPoint(genre1, "nuclear", "2");
        var genre1_3 = new NewPoint(genre1, "nature", "3");
        var genre1_4 = new NewPoint(genre1, "long_ago", "4");
    var genre2 = new NewPoint(start_point, "point-of-view", "2");
        var genre2_1 = new NewPoint(genre2, "first-person", "1");
        var genre2_2 = new NewPoint(genre2, "third-person", "2");
        var genre2_3 = new NewPoint(genre2, "several-points", "3");
        var genre2_4 = new NewPoint(genre2, "constantly-switching", "4");
        var genre2_5 = new NewPoint(genre2, "description", "5");
    var genre3 = new NewPoint(start_point, "fantasy", "3");
        var genre3_1 = new NewPoint(genre3, "mystic", "1");
        var genre3_2 = new NewPoint(genre3, "Fantasy_creatures", "2");
        var genre3_3 = new NewPoint(genre3, "High-Magic", "3");
        var genre3_4 = new NewPoint(genre3, "Low-Magic", "4");
    var genre4 = new NewPoint(start_point, "action", "4");
        var genre4_1 = new NewPoint(genre4, "fighting", "1");
        var genre4_2 = new NewPoint(genre4, "chase", "2");
        var genre4_3 = new NewPoint(genre4, "detective", "3");
        var genre4_4 = new NewPoint(genre4, "adventure", "4");
    var genre5 = new NewPoint(start_point, "main-caracter", "5");
        var genre5_1 = new NewPoint(genre5, "Male", "1");
        var genre5_2 = new NewPoint(genre5, "Female", "2");
        var genre5_3 = new NewPoint(genre5, "Multiple", "3");
        var genre5_4 = new NewPoint(genre5, "Not-human", "4");
        var genre5_5 = new NewPoint(genre5, "Hero", "5");
        var genre5_6 = new NewPoint(genre5, "Antihero", "6");
        var genre5_7 = new NewPoint(genre5, "Weak-to-strong", "7");
        var genre5_8 = new NewPoint(genre5, "character-development", "8");
    var genre6 = new NewPoint(start_point, "relationship", "6");
        var genre6_1 = new NewPoint(genre6, "friends", "1");
        var genre6_2 = new NewPoint(genre6, "romance", "2");
        var genre6_3 = new NewPoint(genre6, "enemies", "3");
        var genre6_4 = new NewPoint(genre6, "found-family", "4");
        var genre6_5 = new NewPoint(genre6, "enemies-to-lovers", "5");
        var genre6_6 = new NewPoint(genre6, "enemies-to-friends", "6");
        var genre6_7 = new NewPoint(genre6, "friends-to-lovers", "7");
    var genre7 = new NewPoint(start_point, "warnings", "7");
        var genre7_1 = new NewPoint(genre7, "death", "1");
        var genre7_2 = new NewPoint(genre7, "violence", "2");
        var genre7_3 = new NewPoint(genre7, "graphic-description", "3");
```

Мне нужно, чтобы выводился список жанров genre1 - genre7, и при выборе любого из них, допустим genre1, открывался еще один список дочерних жанров от выбранного, допустим genre1_1 - genre1_4.
Это должно быть реализовано используя только HTML, JavaScript и(или) CSS. Т.е. без Node js, AJAX, php и прочего.
Просто написать список в HTML не подходит.
UPD: Пожалуйста не меняйте способ, которым заданы жанры, это мне нужно для дальнейшей работы. Да, я знаю, что выглядит плохо.

Comment: То, что нужно - понятно. Теперь поясните в чём проблема и что не так

Comment: Я не понимаю, как мне создать список, в котором пункты будут являться значениями переменных из js.

Comment: да как обычно это делается: через createElement  с установкой атрибутов а-ля `element['attributeName'] = attributeValue`,  потом этот element через например append добавить в контейнер.... а все эти Point можно в массив добавить и потом просто циклом по нему бежать и вызывать метод create (который вы сами напишите как я описал выше)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский можете в ответ написать, как это делается? Желательно с простым примером.

Comment: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-createelement/   ............. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> new genre ... new genre ... new genre

ужс... вот вам для примера двух мерный массив с парой пунктов:

```
   var genres =[
    "post-apocalypse" => [
      "zombie",
      "nuclear",
      "nature",
      "long_ago"],
    "point-of-view" => [
      "first-person",
      "third-person",
      "several-points",
      "constantly-switching",
      "description"]
      ]; // остальное сами вобьете...
```

ну а предсказуемый вывод массивов, конечно же циклом

выборку самого меню из массива можно сделать например так:

```
foreach(genres => k as v){console.log(k)}
/*если есть ошибка сильно не пинайте, js'ный foreach сто лет не юзал*/
```

а его содержимое соответственно так:

```
let i=0; while(genres[k][i]){console.log[k][i++]}
/* k можно получать из onMouseOver */
```

ну а каким способом в html переливать данные, выбирай сам:

1. document.write();
2. в value тега `<output>`
3. innerHTML || outterHTML
4. appendChild(createElement());

---

**UPD 2022.12.1 2:51**

`курсовая`, `на базе этого поисковик`, `главные и дочерние`, `После подтверждения, пойдет поиск по книгам, в id которых есть id соответствующего жанра`

эм... если само по себе изобретение такого "поисковика" не было обязательным заданием без которого курсовую не примут, можно его изобретание просто скипнуть взяв IndexedDB и по человечески построить выборку на sql запросах(по сути это ровно такой поисковик уже готовый, встроенный во все современные браузеры).

если совсем кратко о SQL - таблица в любой БД это двухмерный массив в котором каждое значение является одновременно и значением и ключом. для примера:

```
  [
    [id, mane, famaly] // имена столбцов(задаются при создании таблицы)
    [0, вася, пупкин],
    [1, петя, иванов],
    [2, лёша, ,кружкин]
  ]

  при такой структуре, запрос `select * where id="1"` выдаст: [1, петя, иванов]
  `select name where famaly="кружкин"` выдаст "лёша"
```

> реализовать это через свойство id...потому нужна такая структура

в предложенном мной варианте индексы создаются автоматически которые можно как раз так и использовать, потому и сказал что функционал тот же. впрочем книги не учитывались на тот момент...

если решитесь на вариант с SQL рекомендую такие столбцы:

```
  [id, parent_id, name]
```

> извиняюсь за поведение

у вас прекрасное поведение, тем более по меркам пытающейся самостоятельно склепать курсовую. не за что извиняться =)

---

если indexedDB всё же под запретом, из альтернатив наиболее вменяемым кажется запихнуть всё в один массив, а для перемещений по нему формировать циклом "запрос".

```
  /*немного псевдо-кода, идею думаю поймёте*/
  var genres = [......]; // тут вообще все жанры
  var path = []; // массив для ключей
  <tag value='detective' onclick="x(this.value, path, genres)">
  function x(val, path, genres){
    path.push(val); /* новый ключ при "углублении",
    нужно еще условие для удаления последнего при "всплытии" */
    var targetList=genres, i=-1;
    while(path[++i]){ // дергаем ключи из path "вставляя" в genres
      targetList=targetList[path[i]]
    }
  }
```

ну или куча мелких массивов\объектов почти как у вас, только внутри каждого придется еще создавать массив - список его детей для вывода и чтоб ссылаться на них.

ну как то так

Comment: Как мне сделать список? Я знаю как данные добавить в HTML, как мне их сделать именно как список, а не просто засунутые в div значения переменных? Т.е. чтобы можно было выбрать пункт из списка и с ним дальше работать, а не просто наведением мыши. И да, может это и ужас, но мне нужно именно такое, эту часть пожалуйста не меняйте.

Comment: @DaraHessesh `и дальше с ним работать` смотря что под этим подразумеваете, опишите конкретнее. но если наугад первое что приходит в голову из стандартного - куча radio или select. `но мне нужно именно такое` много почти одинаковых объектов? единственное что кмк это дает, возможность наследовать только один определенный пункт куда угодно или наоборот что угодно наследовать в него. только зачем. один пункт не пару гигов весит, следовательно оперативы на этом не съэкономить... в остальном функционал никак не убавился, скорее даже наоборот.

Comment: Вопрос был не про то, как выглядят мои объекты и как их сделать лучше. Вопрос в том как сделать выпадающий список, пункты которого задаются через javascript. Именно список, а не просто вывод в div в HTML.

Comment: @DaraHessesh, ну так и расскажи что подразумеваешь под "дальше работать с этим списком". без этого совсем не ясно чего хочешь и потому не ясно что советовать

Comment: @puffleek Это моя курсовая, и мне нужно дальше на базе этого сделать поисковик. Идея в том, что есть "главные" жанры, а есть их "дочерние", и если я ищу "главный", мне должны выводиться и дочерние от него, но при поиске дочерних выводится только то, что ищешь. Реализовать это предполагалось через переменную id в каждом жанре (сам поисковик еще не готов). Поэтому мне нужна вот эта структура именно такая, как я ее сделала. Я просто не успеваю переделать даже если вы предложите мне лучший вариант (придется менять отчет, а там много). Допишу следующим комментарием.

Comment: Мне нужно создать выпадающий список с жанрами, при выборе одного жанра должен появляться еще один список с его дочерними жанрами. После подтверждения, пойдет поиск по книгам, в id которых есть id соответствующего жанра.

Comment: Я извиняюсь за свое не очень корректное поведение вчера, тяжелый день.

Comment: @DaraHessesh, дополнил ответ, читайте с метки **UPD 2022.12.1 2:51**

Comment: Спасибо, думаю с такой помощью я разберусь! (Но скорее всего от меня еще будут вопросы по курсовой на этом сайте)